# For %%a in () issue

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I can't get my batch script to work as expected.

Please see below:

```
for %a in (5) do if not exist "%USERPROFILE%\%username%11.txt" (
  IPConfig|FindStr/IRC:"IPv4.*: 10\.0\.%a\.*">Nul 2>&1 && call %LOGONSERVER%\netlogon\printmapsyd.bat
  ) else (

  echo Checking Printers... )
```

The script is supposed to check for number 5 only but it works with 50, 500, 5000, etc. How to limit to check only for **5** ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try with `"IPv4.*: 10\.0\.%a\..*"`?

Comment: Yes, I tried that too.

Comment: How should a *working* regex with a `5` look like?

Comment: @yacc, is correct.  You need two periods.  I tested it like that and it works.

Comment: Of course the third octet of the IP address will **NEVER** be 500 or 5000.

Comment: @yacc. You're a legend! It works as expected. Thank you.

Comment: @ Squashman yes, I added it as an example.

Comment: Thanks to Squashman and yacc the script is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to OP, this works:

```
for %a in (5) do if not exist "%USERPROFILE%\%username%11.txt" (
  IPConfig|FindStr/IRC:"IPv4.*: 10\.0\.%a\..*">Nul 2>&1 && call %LOGONSERVER%\netlogon\printmapsyd.bat
  ) else (
  echo Checking Printers...
  )
```

So there was a `.` missing in the regex. The right regex for `5` would be `IPv4.*: 10\.0\.5\..*`, then.